# FMDB update OR insert query issue "unknown error calling sqlite3_step (5: database is locked) eu"

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, ios10, fmdb

```
let dBName = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String) 
var isUpdated = Bool() 
            if dBName.open()
            {
                isUpdated = dBName.executeUpdate("UPDATE TableName SET \(Column1)=?, \(Column2)=?, \(status)=? WHERE \(ID)=?", withArgumentsInArray: [Column1, Column2, strStatus, strID])
                if isUpdated == true{

                 print("sucess")

                }
                else{

                    print("Error: isUpdated\(dBName.lastErrorMessage())")
                    print("Error: lasterrorcode \(dBName.lastErrorCode())")
                }

                dBName.close()
            }
            else
            {
                print("Error: \(dBName.lastErrorMessage())")
            }
```

**always show error unknown error calling sqlite3_step (5: database is locked) eu. 

Database name is DatabaseName.sqlite, database available in DocumentDirectory 
 
database path is:**

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let filePath = url.URLByAppendingPathComponent(dbName).path!
```

> If file name is DatabaseName.db working properly , no any database lock issue but same issue found if file name is DatabaseName.sqlite

Comment: try clean and run your code again.

Comment: Clean project and derived data remove still not working

Comment: databaseName.executeUpdate("UPDATE TableName SET \(column1)=?, \(column2)=?, \(status)=? WHERE \(ID)=?", withArgumentsInArray: [strColumn1, strColumn2, strStatus, strID])  , Here is query already debug working properly

Answer (score 1):

Also Check if you are accessing same DB file via any other application i.e. say like via SQLite Manager or something. As well if you are in multi threaded environment switch to FMDatabaseQueue 
Check this 
[fmdatabasequeue and thread safety](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/#using-fmdatabasequeue-and-thread-safety)

Answer (score 0):

The value of 5 is **SQLITE_BUSY**, which means that the database is currently busy.(e.g., that a prior SQLite call was not properly finalized and closed).

Possible error conditions are.

1. If you're `executeUpdate` method returning without any outputs. It will silently lock the database. So make sure dBName.close() is working perfectly.
2. Check your SQL syntax that may cause returning `executeUpdate` silently.

log your SQL statement and check the syntax

Comment: You are right , database close is true , So what can i do? , Any solution?  print(database.close()) is always true

Comment: Check your syntax of  sql statement too

Comment: isUpdated = dBName.executeUpdate("UPDATE TableName SET \(Column1)=?, \(Column2)=?, \(status)=? WHERE \(ID)=?", withArgumentsInArray: [Column1, Column2, strStatus, strID]) , working properly

Comment: Not this. log your Statement and check its syntax.

Answer (score 0):

there are many signatures, check if are using the appropiate:

```
database.executeQuery
database.executeUpdate
database.executeStatements
```